# Can ultrasonic and button sensors be run in a VEX analog port?

Tags: sensors

I'm running out of digital ports, and have no sensors that fit the definition 'analog'. Would it be possible to run a [touch sensor, a quadrature encoder, or an ultrasonic sensor on an analog port?](http://www.robotc.net/support/vex/WebHelpCortex/index.htm#page=functions_vex/sensors/VEX_2.0_Cortex_-_Sensors.htm)

I'm thinking not, but I didn't run across anything that said otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying microcontroller in the VEX Cortex is some sort of STM32F1 or STM32F2. I'm not sure which model exactly (just that it's a ST-made Cortex M3), but they all do have digital I/O capabilities on the pins used for analog inputs. Given the bare microcontroller, you could do so.

However, the VEX Cortex is not the bare microcontroller. According to the [documentation](http://www.vexforum.com/wiki/index.php/VEX_Cortex_Microcontroller), the controller board has been designed to add a much higher input impedance to the analog inputs which would likely interfere with digital operation:

> Input Impedance: Analog - The 8 analog inputs each consist of a 470K pull-up to +5V, a series resistance of 10K and a 20K pull-down resistance to the uP.

You can see the difference in the circuit connections on page 13 of the [User's Guide (PDF)](http://content.vexrobotics.com/docs/VEXnet_Cortex_UserGuide_081811.pdf).

Comment: As an aside, if anyone knows what Cortex M3 they're using that they have 5V-tolerant analog inputs I would very much like to know.